# Encoding 2D List

Tags: python, sockets, networking

How can I encode 2D List here to send to the server, so that server can print the 2D List?

ERROR: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

CODE:

`Client.py`

```
from socket import *
serverName = "localhost"
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort))

input = [ 
            [1, 0, 1, 1, 0], 
            [1, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
            [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
        ]

clientSocket.send(input.encode())

clientSocket.close()
```

`Server.py`

```
from socket import *
serverPort = 12000
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)

print("The server is ready to receive!")

while True:
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    array = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
    print(array)
    connectionSocket.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the peer to be able to **print**, or send back the 2D list, you can directly send a string representation:

```
clientSocket.send(str(input).encode())
```

If you want it to be able to process the data as a 2D list, you should *serialize* the list, for example with json:

```
clientSocket.send(json.dumps(input).encode())
```

Then you can retrieve the list with:

```
list2D = json.loads(connectionSocket.recv(1024))
```

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way to do it is to use serialization like [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).
Here is an example with your code, its convert your list into a JSON string and then to bytes before sending it:
`Client.py`

```
from socket import *
import json
serverName = "localhost"
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort))

input = [ 
            [1, 0, 1, 1, 0], 
            [1, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
            [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
        ]

clientSocket.send(json.dumps(input).encode('utf8'))

clientSocket.close()
```

`Server.py`

```
from socket import *
import json
serverPort = 12000
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)

print("The server is ready to receive!")

while True:
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    array = json.loads(connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode('utf8'))
    print(array)
    connectionSocket.close()
```